# Set past background color

Tags: css, background-color, vis.js

I've would like to be able to grey the past of a `vis.js` timeline. I'm able to display it:

```js
  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

var items = new vis.DataSet([]);

var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, {});
```

```html
<script src="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.14.0/vis.css">
<p>
  A basic timeline. You can move and zoom the timeline, and select items.
</p>

<div id="visualization"></div>
```

But I can't find any class like `vis-past` in [the doc](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Styles) to set a background-color.

I would like to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future references, just create an item without content, the shortest date as starting and now as ending:

```
{id: 'past', content: '', start: new Date(-8640000000000000), end: Date(), type: 'background'}
```

Here it is, working:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

var items = new vis.DataSet([{id: 'past', content: '', start: new Date(-8640000000000000), end: Date(), type: 'background'}]);

 var options = {
    start: '2016-01-01',
    end: '2016-04-01',
    editable: false
  };

var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

```css
.vis-item.vis-background {
  background-color: rgba(222,222,222,0.5) !important;
}

body{
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.14.0/vis.css">

<div id="visualization"></div>
```